# I can't boot my iMac to Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, bootcamp, startup, partition

I have Windows (Boot Camp) installed. So I ran out of storage and thought about partitioning my Mac's part of drive. I partitioned my Mac's drive and set Windows to boot by default. Once I lost electricity and my iMac shut down. After this accident I can't see Mac in list of devices to boot. (After pressing alt when Mac is turning on)
But all files are ok. I see them when I use Windows.
Well, Boot Camp Control Panel indicates my Mac-George as Windows:
[image]

Comment: I don't even know what that screenshot is of, but can you please explain how you repartitioned your drive, and if you can get back into OS X.

Comment: Have you tried booting into recovery?

Comment: The first thing you should to is backup all your files.